# Numpy Overflow Error when implementing gradient descent algorithm

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, gradient-descent, calculus

I was trying to learn the gradient descent algorithm purely for fun and I made some code that seems to work event though it get stuck in a local minimum sometimes

but sometimes when I run it works and sometimes it gives an overflow error

#### Output when failed:

```
[2 4 6 8]
E:\Projects\Python\custom_neural_network\testing\testing_gradient_descent.py:18: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
  return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-output))
E:\Projects\Python\custom_neural_network\testing\testing_gradient_descent.py:12: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square
  return sum((yhat - y) ** 2)
Final Loss: inf: inf
Prediction: [-inf -inf -inf -inf]
```

#### Output when successful:

```
[2 4 6 8]
Final Loss: 0.2104827577503237732477
Prediction: [2. 4. 6. 8.]
```

#### Code:

```
import numpy as np
import random

X = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
y = np.array([2, 4, 6, 8])

def neuron_output(X, w, b):
    return np.dot(w, X) + b

def loss_f(yhat, y):
    return sum((yhat - y) ** 2)

def loss_df(yhat, y):
    return sum(2 * (yhat - y))

def sigmoid_activation(output):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-output))

def sigmoid_derivative(output):
    activation = sigmoid_activation(output)
    return activation * (1 - activation)

w = random.uniform(-1, 1)
b = random.uniform(-1, 1)

learning_rate = 0.01
epochs = 100

print(y)

for epoch in range(epochs):
    prediction = neuron_output(X, w, b)
    activation = sigmoid_activation(prediction)

    loss_derivative = loss_df(prediction, y)
    # print(loss_derivative)
    activation_derivative = sigmoid_derivative(activation)

    derivative_wrt_w = np.dot(prediction, loss_derivative)
    derivative_wrt_w = np.dot(derivative_wrt_w, activation_derivative)
    # print(derivative_wrt_w)

    w -=  derivative_wrt_w * learning_rate

    if epoch == epochs - 1:
        print(f"Final Loss: {loss_f(prediction, y)}")
    else:
        print(f"Epoch: {epoch}  Loss: {loss_f(prediction, y)}", end="                                                                     \r")

print(f"Prediction: {np.round(neuron_output(X, w, b))}")
```

How can I fix this issue? thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 0):

Numpy arrays cannot auto promote like Python built-in types. This is because they are fixed to a Data Type to make operations faster which is a reason NumPy is good. Although like in your case, you lose the flexibility that when a number overshoots it automatically changes its datatype to accommodate your needs.

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.types.html#overflow-errors

I would propose jumping to the Overflow error in debug mode and looking at the Datatypes your numpy arrays have, then trying the same calculation with a python array and you will see the difference :D

Comment: thank you for replying, numpy website doesn't open for me, but I fixed the first warning by using the function `scipy.special.expit` instead of `np.exp` and it worked but then I have the second warning `overflow encountered in square` tried changing the array type to `np.float64` but didn't work